# ngAnimate replace one div with another

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Lets say I have the following:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row>
    <div id="first" ng-show="condition" class="in-out">Content here...</div>
    <div id="second" ng-hide="condition" class="in-out">Other Content here...</div>
</div>

</div>

<style>

.in-out.ng-hide-add, .in-out.ng-hide-remove {
  transition:1s linear all;
}

.in-out.ng-hide-add {
  //opacity: 0;
}
.in-out.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;

}
.in-out.ng-hide-remove {
  //opacity: 1;
}
.in-out.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

How can I gracefully replace one div with the other. Which means the following:

1. first is visible, second is not
2. condition changes - first fades away
3. second fades in in the place of first
4. All this without altering the size of the main container

Comment: Should the second start fading in while the first is still fading away, or shall it wait for it to completely fade away first?

Comment: It should wait to fade away.

Comment: Alright, and what AngularJS version? I will provide an answer in a while.